# windowsform c# combobox not selecting bytes

Tags: c#, combobox

```
byte getWeapon(string weapon)
    {
        byte Weapon = 0x00;
        switch (metroComboBox3.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0: Weapon = 0x10; break;
            case 1: Weapon = 0x20; break;
            case 2: Weapon = 0x30; break;
        }
        return Weapon;
    }
    private void metroButton142_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//set button weapons
        byte Weapon = getWeapon (metroComboBox3.SelectedText);
        if (metroComboBox2.SelectedIndex == -1) { MessageBox.Show("Error: Please select a soldier first before proceeding, thank you.", "Selection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
        else if (metroComboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0) PS3.Extension.WriteByte(0x10000000, Weapon);//S1L1
        else if (metroComboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1) PS3.Extension.WriteByte(0x20000000, Weapon);//S1L2
        else if (metroComboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2) PS3.Extension.WriteByte(0x30000000, Weapon);//S1L3           
    }
```

Can someone please help me fix my code.
Its working the way I want but its not selecting the bytes from the metrocombobox3. I believe its the way im calling for selected text and not item, but im not sure how to fix this.
metrocombobox 3 contains bytes but when I select the item in the combobox its not selecting that item. 
When I select something from combobox2 it works fine. But it keeps writing a byte from the...

```
     byte getWeapon(string weapon)
    {
        **byte Weapon = 0x00;**
        switch (metroComboBox3.SelectedIndex)
```

Comment: Can someone please help me with this??

Comment: Is this website active or dead???

Comment: Can someone please help me with this.....